# Adicionar varios objetos em uma lista

Tags: java-ee

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação *web*, onde tenho uma lista de um objeto chamado `frames`, bom, a cada vez que clico em um botão eu adiciono um novo objeto a essa lista, só que o problema é o seguinte: Quando vou tentar adicionar um novo objeto pela 2ª vez à essa lista, o primeiro objeto que foi inserido anteriormente some, como se não fosse inserido nada, ficando apenas o 2º objeto inserido e não o 1º e 2º, ou seja, está guardando sempre o último objeto inserido. Como faço para que guarde quantos objetos forem necessários para adicionar a essa lista?

Bom eu tenho isso até o momento, quando o usuário clicar em adicionar, irá abrir uma tela para preencher algumas informações sobre o qual objeto mencionei: Esse é o botão:

```
  <p:commandLink id="btn_close_users_modal3" actionListener="#{messageBean.insertFrame()}" 
                                               styleClass="btn btn-default" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw" /> #{bundle['system.ui.label.add.frameAdd']}
                                </p:commandLink>
```

E esse é o meu método, na qual o que tem que fazer e depois adiciona em uma lista.

```
public void insertFrame() {
    try {
        // caso nao visualize a mensagem e salve direto, chama de qualquer forma esse metodo
        teste();

        frame.setContent(svg);
        frame.setWriteContent(objSvg.getValueText1() + " / " + objSvg.getValueText2());
        frame.setRemoved("f");

        frame.setOrder(1);
        frame.setLogo('f');

        listAllFrames.add(frame);

        MessageGrowl.info(MessageProperties.getString("message.sucesso"));
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('framesModal').hide();");

        //     frameFacade.save(frame);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ivan, procure disponibilizar o que você já tem feito até o momento, isso garante uma atenção maior a sua dúvida, se possível edite sua pergunta com um exemplo mínimo para reprodução da questão.

Comment: "Lista" é um termo ambíguo num contexto Java. Isso é uma List, ou uma ArrayList, ou outra coisa? Poste código e evidencie ou simule o problema específico, senão fica difícil dar uma resposta concreta.

Comment: fiz a edição na pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro.

Comment: Seu `listAllFrames` é instanciado como?

Comment: listAllFrames = new ArrayList<>(); primeiro eu estava instanciando, depois eu retirei desse metodo ai

Comment: Ivan, se você estava instanciando dentro do método a cada chamada do método é uma nova ArrayList criada, e dispensada quando se retorna do método. O correto é você instancia-la como propriedade da classe.

É melhor você postar todo o código da Classe, ou pelo menos mais detalhes relevantes a este processo.

Comment: Relacionado [Por que não consigo acessar os elementos dentro de uma ArrayList com um for?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169084/por-que-n%C3%A3o-consigo-acessar-os-elementos-dentro-de-uma-arraylist-com-um-for/169160#169160)

Answer (score 1):

Eu creio que o que aconteça é o reuso do objeto chamado `frame`.

No seu código, em nenhum momento você cria um novo objeto para chamar de `frame`; você simplesmente continua usando o mesmo objeto para tudo. Java trabalha a nível de referência de objeto, portanto na lista `listAllFrames` são guardadas as diversas referências a esses objetos. Assim, se você adicionou o objeto à lista e depois editou esse objeto, quando você pegar a lista, você verá que o objeto da lista também sofreu a mesma mudança.

Experimente esse código aqui de baixo para melhor entendimento:

```
class SeguraNumero {
    public int numero;
}

void reaproveitandoObjeto() {
    ArrayList<SeguraNumero> l = new ArrayList<>();
    SeguraNumero segura = new SeguraNumero();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        segura.numero = i;
        l.add(segura);
    }
    for (SeguraNumero segura: l) {
        System.out.println("segurou o numero " + l.numero);
    }
}


void novosObjetos() {
    ArrayList<SeguraNumero> l = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SeguraNumero segura = new SeguraNumero();
        segura.numero = i;
        l.add(segura);
    }
    for (SeguraNumero segura: l) {
        System.out.println("segurou o numero " + l.numero);
    }
}
```

A função `reaproveitandoObjeto` é análoga ao que você escreveu, já a `novosObjetos` não reaproveita os objetos anteriores; creio eu que você deveria ter feito algo mais análogo ao `novosObjetos`

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode estar ocorrendo porque o programa está interpretando o objeto que está na lista e o objeto que você está adicionando, como o mesmo objeto! Assim, ele apenas muda a referencia de memoria do objeto, retirando da posição anterior e colocando na posição atual que você inseriu.

Tente fazer uma cópia do objeto antes de adicioná-lo na lista, assim você terá 2 objetos e não 1 só!

**Exemplo:**

```
Frame f = new Frame();
f = frame;
listAllFrames.add(f);
```

Comment: Na segunda linha, você destruiu o `Frame` criado na primeira linha...