# Por que não consigo acessar os elementos dentro de uma ArrayList com um for?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou tentando preencher uma JTable com elementos que estão dentro de uma ArrayList, que está dentro de outro objeto:

```
private void jButtonConfirmarProdutoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    modProduto.setQuantidade(Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldQnt.getText()));
    modVenda.itens.add(modProduto);
    jTable1 = ctrl.fillTable(jTable1, modVenda);
}
```

Essas são as classes:

```
public class ModeloVenda {

    private int idVenda;
    private String data;
    private float valorVenda;
    private int idCliente;
    public final ArrayList<ModeloProduto> itens;
}

public class ModeloProduto {
    private int id_produto;
    private String nome;
    private float preco_compra;
    private float preco_venda;
    private int quantidade;
    private int fornecedor;

public float calculaTotal(int quantidade){
    return preco_venda*quantidade;
}}
```

Essa é a função que preenche a tabela:

```
public JTable fillTable(JTable tabela, ModeloVenda mod){
    ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
    String[] Collums= new String[]{"Nome", "Valor Unitário", "Quantidade", "Valor Total"};
    for(int i = 0; i < mod.itens.size(); i++){
        dados.add(new Object[]{mod.itens.get(i).getNome(), 
            mod.itens.get(i).getPreco_venda(), mod.itens.get(i).getQuantidade(), 
            mod.itens.get(i).calculaTotal(mod.itens.get(i).getQuantidade())});
    }
    ModeloTabela modelo = new ModeloTabela(dados, Colunas);
    tabela.setModel(modelo);

    for(int i = 0; i<Colunas.length; i++){
        tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(150);
        tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setResizable(false);
    }
    tabela.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    tabela.setAutoResizeMode(tabela.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    tabela.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    return tabela;
}
```

Mas quando eu adiciono outro elemento na array e atualizo a tabela todos os elementos são substituídos pelo novo:
[image: First Element Added]
[image: Second Element Added]

Comment: teu problema tá no `jButtonConfirmarProdutoActionPerformed`, você tem que criar um novo `modProduto` pra cada vez que você adiciona na lista. Você está adicionando diversas vezes o mesmo item sem nunca criar o novo, e ainda pior, está alterando-o no decorrer do código

Comment: @Sorack, obrigado, isso resolveu o problema, eu achava que a função arraylist.add criava um novo objeto e passava os parâmetros, e não que ele usava o mesmo objeto. Obrigado

Comment: @Sorack agora que a pergunta reabriu, seria interessante postar seu comentario como resposta, para "fechar" a questao como solucionada.

Comment: @diegofm postei a resposta, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Vamos supor que você tenha uma classe item:

```
public class Item {

  String descricao;

  public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
  }

  public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.descricao;
  }
}
```

E tenha o seguinte método:

```
List<Item> itens = new ArrayList<>();
Item item = new Item();

item.setDescricao("Descrição A");
itens.add(item);
item.setDescricao("Descrição B");
itens.add(item);
item.setDescricao("Descrição C");
itens.add(item);

System.out.println(itens);
```

A saída seria:

> [Descrição C, Descrição C, Descrição C]

**Por que?**

Porque você instanciou só uma vez cada item, assim ao alterar alguma propriedade você apenas alterava do item original e replicava as referências a este mesmo item na sua lista.

**E como resolver?**

O correto seria você criar uma instância para cada item da seguinte forma:

```
List<Item> itens = new ArrayList<>();

Item itemA = new Item();
itemA.setDescricao("Descrição A");
itens.add(itemA);
Item itemB = new Item();

itemB.setDescricao("Descrição B");
itens.add(itemB);

Item itemC = new Item();
itemC.setDescricao("Descrição C");
itens.add(itemC);

System.out.println(itens);
```

Onde a saída seria:

> [Descrição A, Descrição B, Descrição C]

**E onde isso se encaixa no se problema?**

No método `jButtonConfirmarProdutoActionPerformed`, você tem que criar um novo `modProduto` pra cada vez que você adiciona na lista senão estará, assim como no exemplo, apenas replicando a referência a um objeto só.